# No power pivot in MS Office Home & Student edition

Tags: powerpivot

I have Windows 10 (64 bit) with MS office Home & Student edition but it does not have Power Pivot, Power Query or Power Map. How to install Power Pivot, power query ?
regards
Partha

Answer (score 0):

Power Pivot is not included in Office Home & Student (one time purchase licence) versions.

You can see a full list of Office / Excel versions which include PowerPivot here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/where-is-power-pivot-aa64e217-4b6e-410b-8337-20b87e1c2a4b